# Python Salesforce Beatbox cannot import _tPartnerNS

Tags: python, python-2.7, salesforce, beatbox

I am trying to use Python and beatbox to login to Salesforce but am running to some issues:

MY Code:

```
import beatbox
from beatbox import _tPartnerNS
print "Enter your login: "
mylogin = raw_input()
print "password: "
password = raw_input()

sf = beatbox._tPartnerNS
svc=beatbox.Client()
```

I am getting the error saying `ImportError: cannot import name _tPartnerNS`. If I take out the `from beatbox import _tPartnerNS` line then I get the error  `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_tPartnerNS'`

Comment: Did you try running one of the samples, e.g. export.py? do you have the current version of Beatbox?

Comment: make sure you're using beatbox from https://github.com/superfell/Beatbox

Comment: Truth is, you don't need that "from beatbox import _tPartenerNS", because you're telling python to look for _tPartnerNS in beatbox module already. And you don't need that sf = ... for most applications. For the svc, use svc = beatbox.PythonClient()